# I am trying to make a responsive image inside a div

Tags: html, css

everything is fine except when I break past 1768px the box starts activg weird and cutting half the image

```css
.Background-Header{
    width: 100%;
    /*display: 100%;*/
    height:1487px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    border: black solid 10px;
    background: url(BackgroundImageGE.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    image-rendering: auto;
  
  }
```

```html
 <div class="Background-Header"> </div>
```

[BackgroundImageGE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Diq.jpg)

Comment: are you using any other css libraries? maybe the the library has a breakpoint set that's tweaking the style after 1768. Bootstrap has a lot of predefined breakpoints.

Comment: You are bound to get some of the image cropped as using cover, but could you show us what happens at the large size? An image of what it looks like would be helpful, as would a snippet which we could run to see the problem because the code you have given isn't going to produce a problem particularly.